# Asynchronous jobs in for loop in python

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a function

```
async def hello(a):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print(a)
```

I want to call this function for several elements in a list asynchronously

```
list =  ['words','I','need','to','print','parallely']
```

Something like this, but the below code runs one after the other.

```
for word in list:
    await hello(word)
```

Is there a better way to do this? I had used `asyncio.create_task` but not sure how to use them in loops.

Comment: Do not use `list` as a variable name, it shadows built-in type `list`.

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of how it should work:

```
import asyncio

list_1 = 'hi i am cool'.split()

async def hello(a):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print(a)
    
async def run_tasks():
   tasks = [hello(word) for word in list_1]
   await asyncio.wait(tasks)

def main():
   loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
   asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
   loop.run_until_complete(run_tasks())
   loop.close()

main()
```

Sample output:

```
am
i
cool
hi
```

The above code is mainly for demonstration but the new and easier way to do so is:

```
def main2():
    asyncio.run(run_tasks())

main2()
```

Sample output:

```
i
hi
cool
am
```

Note:

As suggested in the comments, to preserve the order of inputs, define run_tasks as:

```
async def run_tasks():
   tasks = [hello(word) for word in list_1]
   await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Comment: To preserve the order of inputs, can use `asyncio.gather(*tasks)`.

Comment: is that waht you meant?

Comment: Yes. If you run that, it should print "hi" "I" "am" "cool" in order.

Comment: RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
 
Getting this error for the same code given above while running main()

Comment: import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

added these two lines and its working! thanks